# Quasilinear utility: if $x \succeq y - ae_1$, does it mean $x + ae_1 \succeq y$?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Quasilinear preference is defined to be:

$x \sim y \Rightarrow x+ae_1 \sim y+ae_1$ and $x + ae_1 \succ x$ with $e_1 = (1,0,0,...)$,

Given a quasilinear preference, if f $x  \succeq y - ae_1$, does it mean $x + ae_1 \succeq y$?

I know that $x + ae_1 \succ x$ but how do I compare $x+ae_1$ with $y$? Drawing a diagram makes me see it but I can't prove it rigorously.

EDIT: Included the definition for quasilinear preference.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "quasilinear preference". Doing so may help you answer your own question.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Now that you have included your definition, are you sure you do not know how to proceed? There is no trick at all, you just apply the definition.

Comment: Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: If the OP had used the utility function definition of quasilinear preferences, the question would be easy. However, the OP is using a different definition which makes the problem more difficult and more interesting.

Comment: If the preference isn't continuous we aren't sure we can use utility function either... so we're stuck with this definition.

Comment: Hint: Let $z=y-a\mathbf e_1$, so that $x\succsim y-a\mathbf e_1$ becomes $x\succsim z$. Apply the definition of quasilinear preference.

Comment: The definition applies to  $\sim$, does it apply to $ \succ$?

Comment: Sure it does. If not, you'll have $x\succ y$ implying $y+a\mathrm e_1\succsim x+a\mathrm e_1$, which is a contradiction when $a=0$.